# Rails: NoMethodError on creating has_one association with devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am a complete beginner in Rails as such and I am trying to build a page to add extra profile data once the user logs in.

I am using Devise for authentication purposes and that works fine.  I get this error and I have been stuck here.

> undefined method `profiles'

Can you please help?

**Codes**

*profiles_controller.rb*

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :show]

  def new
    @profile = current_user.profiles.build
  end

  def create
    @profile = current_user.profiles.build(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
      format.html {redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'}
    else
      format.html {render 'new'}
    end

  end

  def show
    @profile = current_user.profiles
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

The error seems to be coming from these lines in particular

```
  def new
    @profile = current_user.profiles.build
  end
```

Other codes for reference:

*/views/profiles/new.html.erb*

```
<h1>Profiles#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/profiles/new.html.erb</p>

<h3>Welcome <%= current_user.email %></h3>

<%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :text, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'profiles/new'

  get 'profiles/create'

  get 'profiles/show'

  get 'profiles/update'

  get 'pages/home'

  get 'pages/dashboard'

  devise_for :users,  controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
  resources :profiles


  root 'pages#home'

  devise_scope :user do
    get "user_root", to: "page#dashboard"
  end
end
```

*models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
end
```

*models/profile.rb*

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Can you post the full error? Also, can you post your User model?

Comment: Hey Anthony,

I just figured it out!  The relationship is *has_one*.

So, it should be    `@profile = current_user.build_profile` instead of `@profile=current_user.profiles.build`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out!

As the relationship is has_one, we should be using

```
def new
   @profile = current_user.build_profile
end
```

instead of

```
def new
   @profile = current_user.profiles.build
end
```

according to the documentation - 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call an undefined relationship:

```
  def new
    @profile = current_user.profiles.build
  end

  has_one :profile
```

You should be calling:

```
  def new
    @profile = current_user.build_profile
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge.  But this gives build method is not defined.
I just figured it out.  It was in the documentation :(

Answer (score 1):

**1)** If your user must have many profiles. Set in your app/models/user.rb `has_many :profiles`

**2)**  In your ProfilesController in new method instead of `@profile = current_user.profiles` use `@profile = Profile.new`

**3)** In your routes.rb delete

```
  get 'profiles/new'

  get 'profiles/create'

  get 'profiles/show'

  get 'profiles/update'
```

because you have already used `resources :profiles`

**4)** To stay with rules of DRY you can render form from a partial. Just add in views/profiles/_form.html.erb with the same content in your new.html.erb and after this you can delete everything im new.htm.erb and paste `<%= render "form" %>`. In future it will help you to render edit form if you want.

**5)** In your ProfilesController you can add method index with all profiles

```
def index
  @profiles = Profile.all
end
```